# Example for violation of a property

Tags: probability-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of positive integrable random variables, which converges almost everywhere to an integrable random variable $X$. Suppose

$$E(X_n) \rightarrow E(X)$$

I showed that all bounded random variables Y, $E(YX_n) \rightarrow E(YX)$.

But I am unable to get an example, in which the above conclusion is false, if $X_n$ is not positive. Can someone give me one?

Comment: Try $P(Y=1)=P(Y=-1)=\frac12$, $P(Z_n=n^2)=\frac1{n^2}$, $P(Z_n=0)=1-\frac1{n^2}$, $(Z_n)$ and $Y$ all independent, and $X_n=YZ_n$, then $X_n\to0$ almost surely, $E(X_n)=0$, but $YX_n=Z_n$ hence $E(YX_n)=1$ for every $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\Omega = (0,1)$ with Borel sets and Lebesgue measure and define the random variables:

$$
X_n(\omega) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
n, & \omega \in (0,\frac{1}{n})\\
-n, &\omega \in (1-\frac{1}{n}, 1) 
\\ 
0, &else \end{matrix}\right.
$$

Also let $X(\omega)=0$, then $X_n \to X$ almost surely, $E[X_n]=0$ and $E[X]=0$, so that the limiting result $E[X_n] \to E[X]$ also holds.

Now let $Y(\omega) = 1$ for $\omega < \frac{1}{2}$ and $Y(\omega) = -1$ for $\omega \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

Then $E[XY]=0$ still but $E[X_nY] = 1$, which of course does not converge to 0.